# Android HAL debugging: How to enable logcat

Tags: android, adb, android-source, hal

How do I get Android logs if device doesn't boot to UI?

Background:

I am attempting to add a new HAL to AOSP. Details on platform:
AOSP 6.0.1_r25
Nexus 7 2013 (flo)
build type: eng

I added a new Audio HAL to AOSP, under devices/asus/flo/audio, built and flashed image.

Device doesn't boot beyond Android logo during boot.

adb shell says:

`error: insufficient permissions for device`

adb logcat is just

`- waiting for device -`

I know these work when I select any option other than `"USB for Charging"` but I can't get to that without booting fully.

Now I could debug issues in my code, if only I could get logs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepare a special engineering boot image that will allow you to get logs freely during the bootup.

I can also advise you to boot with the original HAL, switch them on the fly and kill the mediaserver binary, this will cause the system to load your audio HAL.

Comment: Can you please point me to mods I need in AOSP for this eng build? 
Also, on kill/restart of mediaserver, does it also load audio policy? I guess it would but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Killing mediaserver tip was useful. Thanks. Would really appreciate if you could point to resources for other method.

Comment: Accepted as correct answer. eng builds enable USB/TCP logcat on boot.

Comment: In latest Android I think there is audioserver instead of mediaserver.